# How to print data from two files in a single line (horizontal) in c++ ? As given. These two forms are from two different text files

Tags: c++, file, text, file-io, output

```
...ifstream myfile("all_good/2.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())

while (getline(myfile, line))
{
cout << line << '\n';
}
myfile.close();
}
else
{
cout << "Unable to open file";
}
}

ifstream myfile("all_good/3.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
while (getline(myfile, line))
{
cout << line << '\n';
}
myfile.close();
}
else
{
cout << "Unable to open file";
}
}...
```

How I can achieve this format. These are two formats from two different text files so how I can print files in this sequence in the same line horizontally?

---

-2--------2-  -3--------3-

---

---

---

---

---

-2--------2-  -3--------3-

---

Answer (score 0):

Do operations on both files in lock-step. First open both files, then read from both files, and print out lines in lock-step. Something like this:

```
ifstream myfile2("all_good/2.txt");
ifstream myfile3("all_good/3.txt");

if (myfile2.is_open() && myfile3.is_open())
{
  while (getline(myfile2, line2) && getline(myfile3, line3))
  {
    cout << line2 << line3 << '\n';
  }
  myfile2.close();
  myfile3.close();
}
else
{
  cout << "Unable to open files";
}
```